# Find the winner, player with max points

Tags: excel

please give me a hint on how to make this table.

| Turn | Player | Points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Player1 | 10 |
| 2 | Player3 | 15 |
| 3 | Player1 | 22 |
| 4 | Player6 | 10 |

...and so on. Basically, each turn some player earns some points. We don't know the number of players until the end, so I can't just make a list of players aside and SUMIF their points.
I only need to find the WINNER, a player with the maximum amount of points, i.e. in this table it would be Player1 with 10+22=32 points.
I only need one cell with WINNER: Player7

Is there a nice solution for this?

I'm using Excel 365, but vba is not allowed.

Comment: [Super User](https://superuser.com/) seems to be the more appropriate site for Excel questions.

Comment: `=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH(MAX(C2:C5),C2:C5,0))`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad  Sorry, my explanation was bad. This will only find a player with max points in some turn. But players can do many turns.

Comment: I think you'll need to create a separate table listing all the players and summing all their scores and get the max from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365:

```
=LET(
    ply,B2:B5,
    pts,C2:C5,
    unq,UNIQUE(ply),
    INDEX(SORTBY(unq,SUMIFS(pts,ply,unq),-1),1,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start by limiting the size of the table, e.g. to 500 rows.
You could make it a million rows, but it will slow the calculation

1. Title Column D "Cumulative Points".
2. In cell D2 enter "`=SUMIF(B$2:B2,B2,C$2:C2)`" and copy it down the column to 500 rows
   In cell D3, this will become "`=SUMIF(B$2:B3,B3,C$2:C3)`" etc.
3. Title Column E "Player"
4. In cell E2 write "`= B2`" and copy it down 500 rows
5. Title Column G "Winner"
6. In cell G2 write "`=VLOOKUP(MAX(D$2:D$500),$D$2:$E$500,2,FALSE)`"
7. Hide columns D and E

[image: Picture of spreadsheet before hiding cells]